# Oracle SQL query to fetch manyToMany record in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following three tables, my requirement is to fetch manytoMany joined tabled as a column. Can someone pls help me in writing the query.
IPtype can only be of two types public and private, so the result should have two more columns as mentioned below. If there is multiple public or private ip mapped to single asset then is should be displayed as comma separated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `outer join` (to return assets that don't have any IP addresses) with `listagg` (to aggregate IP addresses per asset) problem.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- Sample data
  3  asset (assetid) as
  4    (select 1 from dual union all
  5     select 2 from dual union all
  6     select 3 from dual union all
  7     select 4 from dual
  8    ),
  9  ip (ipid, ipnumber, iptype) as
 10    (select 1, '1.2.3.4'  , 'Public'  from dual union all
 11     select 2, '99.22.3.4', 'Private' from dual union all
 12     select 3, '11.22.3.4', 'Public'  from dual union all
 13     select 4, '55.22.3.4', 'Public'  from dual union all
 14     select 5, '66.22.3.4', 'Private' from dual union all
 15     select 6, '77.22.3.4', 'Private' from dual
 16    ),
 17  asset_ip_map (assetid, ipid) as
 18    (select 1, 1 from dual union all
 19     select 1, 2 from dual union all
 20     select 2, 3 from dual union all
 21     select 2, 4 from dual union all
 22     select 3, 5 from dual union all
 23     select 3, 6 from dual
 24    )
 25  -- Query you need
 26  select a.assetid,
 27    listagg(case when iptype = 'Public'  then i.ipnumber end, ', ') within group (order by null) public_ip,
 28    listagg(case when iptype = 'Private' then i.ipnumber end, ', ') within group (order by null) private_ip
 29  from asset a left join asset_ip_map m on m.assetid = a.assetid
 30               left join ip i on i.ipid = m.ipid
 31  group by a.assetid
 32  order by a.assetid;

   ASSETID PUBLIC_IP                      PRIVATE_IP
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 1.2.3.4                        99.22.3.4
         2 11.22.3.4, 55.22.3.4
         3                                66.22.3.4, 77.22.3.4
         4

SQL>
```